# Unable to load project home page

Tags: tuleap

Creating a new project, it's impossible to open the home page related (the service "Home page" is enabled). Eg: at http://mytuleaphost/www/newproject, I receive the message `<<Sorry, page not found>>`

All other services (forum, lists, documents) work fine.

Is there anything obvious I could be missing with tuleap?

Comment: where are you receiving '<>'?

Answer (score 3):

I just hit the same problem :).

It turns out that right after installation DNS delegation is not enabled (that is http://projectname.tuleap.host will not work) and at the same time /www/project name alias is disabled.

Go to /etc/httpd/conf.d directory and in file codendi_aliases.conf look for "Codendi without the DNS delegation" and uncomment lines:

```
AliasMatch ^/www/([^/]*)/(.*) /home/groups/$1/htdocs/$2
<Directory /home/groups>
...
</Directory>
```

Then restart server ("sudo service httpd restart") and it should be working.